# How to install Sun/Oracle Java 1.6 onto centOS 6 using only textmode?

Tags: centos, software-installation, java

So, after a few days of struggle I have yet to be successful in installing Sun/Oracle java 1.6 onto my CentOS.

The issues seem to be as follows

- No sun java 1.6 package available in repo due to license issues
- The alternative is to download an rpm from the oracle site

  - Problem with that is, I'm using text mode only, so I tried to use lynx.
  - Problem with lynx is, Oracle demands you accept the license prior to download, but the facility with which it presents the license prompt(JavaScript) does not function within lynx.

So, the question remains, how do I get java 1.6 (sun) onto my CentOS system using only textmode?

Comment: Download the RPM on another machine and then scp it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wget` to download the latest version of Java 6 via the command line on this server.

```
$ wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" \
    "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin"
```

Once you've downloaded it, you'll need to do these steps:

```
$ chmod +x jdk-6u45-linux-x64-rpm.bin
```

And then use either `rpm` or `yum` to install the bundled RPM files.

#### References

- [Java previous versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR)
- [How to automate download and instalation of Java JDK on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268583/how-to-automate-download-and-instalation-of-java-jdk-on-linux)